# using getPreferece() to set a first time run flag

Tags: android, preferences

I have this code that should read an unset preference on the first run:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    firstTime = settings.getBoolean("firstTime", true);
    Log.d("mything", "firstTime returns as: " + firstTime);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("firstTime", false);
    editor.commit();
```

the variable "firstTime" is always returned as false.
I am uninstalling my app and loading it afresh.

Can someone explain?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Samsung Galaxy S with 2.2.1 firmware?  There is known bug that shared preferences are not being removed if application is uninstalled. For example see comments [here](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer&hl=en)

Comment: Yes indeed I am. . That could explain why I'm having this trouble. Failed to find the comments in your linkthoough? Thanks

Comment: Switch to english version of market and see that stated in description.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm strange. I run your code and work as expected. The first time you run it is logs

```
05-10 14:53:59.390: DEBUG/mything(4895): firstTime returns as: true
```

and if you run it again it always logs

```
05-10 14:55:25.780: DEBUG/mything(4895): firstTime returns as: false
```

Are you sure you are not missing something in the log ?

Comment: Hi thanks, you're right it does work in a pure android app. It seems to be some interaction with the libgdx library I'm using.