# android:defaultValue not working on some phones - Workaround?

Tags: android, android-preferences, galaxy

I need the default value set in the preferences XML to be available on **first** run.

In some phones this works, but some other phones (e.g. [Samsung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949525/using-getpreferece-to-set-a-first-time-run-flag/5949726#5949726)) behave very strangely.

In my particular case, the following code:

```
String key = "@string/timeout_key"
timeout = Integer.valueOf(prefs.getString(key, "10"));
```

Keeps returning (to `timeout`) the default value of "10" (passed as the 2nd parameter to `prefs.getString()`), although the preferences XML specifies:

```
android:defaultValue="5"
```

The string "timeout_key" exists and I could verify that it is read correctly.

My "manual workaround" currently is to invoke the settings editor, retype the setting and press OK.

Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SharedPreferences.getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method is buggy and won't return `android:defaultValue`. It will only return the second param if read fails. To work around this, put **null** in the second param:

```
timeout = Integer.valueOf(prefs.getString(key, null));
```

This will of course throw an exception the first time you call it after installing the app, so what you do is enclose it in a `try` and when catching the exception, write your default (the one in your android:defaultValue, originally intended to be used if Android wasn't buggy):

```
try {
  timeout = Integer.valueOf(prefs.getString(key, null));
}
catch (Exception e) {
  Editor editor = prefs.edit();
  editor.putString(key, Integer.toString(defaultValue));
  editor.commit();
}
```

Ugly, but works.